Ubuntu 22.04/24.04 microsemi RAID cache controller causes forced UNMOUNT during heavy write activities
I do have a really strange yet reproducible problem, identical on similar machines

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 or 24.04 (on a separate RAID-1 array)
RAID-Controller: Adaptec microsemi 3152-8i, 2GB cache, running additional RAID 5 & 6 arrays of 40TB or more
PC: 40 core, 128GB RAM
Virtual memory: 128GB

Whenever I write (rsync) large amount of files up to 120GB or more (filesize) up to 230GB or more (total transfer) to the large RAID-arrays, the PC stops its write procedure and "unmounts" the arrays (OS disk is not impaired).
A forced reboot then brings the PC to write large amounts of data for more than 10 minutes to the OS disk before finally rebooting the regular way.
I have no idea on where to start searching in the logfiles or what to look for.

rsync-option --bwlimit=50m also doesn't resolve this problem. Any idea?

Update: this "hang" also appears after extended READ operations.

Next update:
I am trying to circumvent this by every 5 minutes to clear the cache:
sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

Up to now this seems to work. Interesting enough, when doing same size of rsync to notebooks running M." SSDs, it works flawlessly.
